# please how can i really import kivy to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I  installed kivy using the command line as instructed in the kivy.. except for last part which says "python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1" which i tried to install according to the instruction from the site...but its giving me error messages so after some research it seems like python 3.8 does no support kivy..but i did install it manually..the main issue now is that i can't import kivy to pycharm it gives me error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'"
please what is the correct way to import kivy to pycharm?

Comment: Follow this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: This is a good question, but you don't need to use "please" that often. Once is fine, but you should know that everyone will do their best to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just solved Your problem. Use this:

```
 python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Write this on PyCharm terminal and you are done!

Comment: it install successfully in pycharm...but when i type "import kivy" the error message is still there "C:\Users\Toshiba\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Toshiba/PycharmProjects/kivyproject1/ivy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Toshiba/PycharmProjects/kivyproject1/ivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'"

Comment: As I understand from the documentarys of Kivy, you should be running your program normal. Can you try 'import kivy_exmaples"?